# Simple fadeIn and visibility in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the css property `visibility` of a div to `visible`with a jQuery `.fadeIn()`transition.

Here is my code :

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#test').fadeIn('slow', function() {
     $(this).css('visibility','visible');
  });
});​
```

and the fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/np6r7/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot animate `visibility`. `fadein` is keyed off `display:none;`, so that should be `#test`'s initial state via CSS. If you need to keep the layout, you can try wrapping test in a div that specifies the height and/or width you need.

Comment: I think fadeIn also requires display:none

Comment: also if you don't want to have the empty space you can hide the element just before fading it, like this: `$('#test').hide().fadeIn('slow', function() {
     $(this).css('visibility','visible');
  });`

Comment: @davidaam I believe a more simple and correct form would be `$("#test").hide().css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn();`. It works for me.

Answer (score 30):

Actually, I liked [davidaam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235095/davidaam)'s answer.  I would make a slight modification:

```
    $('#test').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 13):

You could also use CSS opacity combined with JQuery's fadeIn to achieve the same thing.

Instead of using visibility in your CSS, use `opacity: 0;`
Then use jQuery `FadeTo` to increase the opacity to 100%:

`$('#test').fadeTo('slow', 1);`

This will preserve positioning like visibility does, however, it's important to note that `opacity: 0` responds to events such as click and keypress as well as participating in the taborder. Additionally, I've also read that a *responsible* use of `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none` is better for SEO, but I'm not sure how this applies to `opacity: 0`.

***JSFIDDLE***: http://jsfiddle.net/np6r7/15/

Comment: The trouble with this can be, of course, that the element responds to clicks/mouseovers/etc. This may not always been an issue but was for my case.

Comment: `.hide().fadeIn("slow");` resulted in content shifting back and forth for me. `.css('opacity', '0').fadeTo('slow', 1);` do not have that problem.