# Fade in with CSS visibility: visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` to show and hive divs, such as modals and other divs. I'd like to have a fade-in effect when clicking the `<a>` link to run the javascript to show and hide the divs, but I'd very strongly like to continue using the `visibility` element to toggle the div visibility. Is there a way to do this with HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Opacity is the only way to fade something in/out.

Comment: @Shmiddty could you fade it out all the way, then make it `hidden`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple fadeIn and visibility in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942098/simple-fadein-and-visibility-in-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in jQuery:

```
$('selector').fadeIn();
```

With CSS, use opacity: (this is 50%)

```
-moz-opacity:.50; 
filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
opacity:.50;
```

If you would like to do the fadeIn manually, adjust this opacity in steps, and when you reach the point of invisibilty, add `display:none` But if you use jQuery anyways, stick with `fadeIn()`

`fadeIn()` supports speed too, just add the milliseconds as first parameter. Look at the docs: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Want to keep the `display` property in css, use `fadeTo()`. It requires the opacity percentage: http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1); // 100% visible
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0); // 0% visible aka hidden
```

Comment: wouldn't that make it still stay "there", but not visible? Would things below it be clickable?

Comment: @tkbx added solution for it inline. `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` handles it. But the manual thing doesn't. You need to change `display:none` too.

Comment: @RenePot I believe the OP doesn't want to use `display:none` because it will cause elements in flow layout after it to move.

Comment: If `visibility: hidden`, `.fadeIn()`  doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you want to use visibility:hidden instead of display:none so that you see an empty space.

If so fadeIn() and fadeOut() won't work for you because it sets the display to none after it fades out.

Instead use jQuery animate() to animate the opacity and then add visibility:hidden/visible in the callback.

Here is how I would do it with jQuery.

```
$('#a-id').click(
  if( $('#div-id').css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
    $('#div-id').animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast', function(){
    $('#div-id').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
  }else{
    $('#div-id').animate({opacity: 0}, 'fast', function(){
    $('#div-id').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
);
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing it but this works without problems afaik.

Comment: You can use a callback function with `fadeOut` as well. `$('#div-id').fadeOut(function() { $('#div-id').css('display', 'block').css('visibility', 'hidden');  })`

Comment: @Skillzore I tried using `fadeIn` with a callback and although it works it does it immediately, with no fading, tried "slow", "fast" and 500 - no fade at all

Answer (score 6):

You can also accomplish this with css3: http://jsfiddle.net/dc7EV/

```
$("#hideme").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("fadein").addClass("fadeout");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#hideme").removeClass("fadeout").addClass("fadein");
    }, 2000);
});​
```

CSS

```
#hideme{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeout{
    0%{opacity:1;visibility:visible;}
    99%{opacity:0;}
    100%{opacity:0;visibility: hidden;}
}
.fadeout {
    -webkit-animation:fadeout 1s linear;
    visibility:hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
    0%{opacity:0;visibility:visible;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
}
.fadein {
    -webkit-animation:fadein 1s linear;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Rene's answer, but if you strongly want to use the visibility attribute (as you say you do), then you can use css() to do so:

```
$('selector').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('selector').css('visibility', 'visible');
```